# Archive data in Grails

Tags: grails

In my grails application I have some domain objects with lots of data in it. I now want to archive the old data in a seperate table, but the user should have access to it. 
Do I have to make an extra domain class? Or is there some plugin which will help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no plugin that would meet your requirements. You would need to model this with a new Domain class (or something similar) in order to address your requirements.